Why can the rust compiler not figure out the appropriate function to call in generic template specialization?
Consider the following code:
trait A {}

struct X { p1: i32 }
struct Y { p1: i32, p2: i32 }

impl A for X {}
impl A for Y {}

struct Z<T> where T: A {
    data: T
}

impl Z<X> {
    fn new(p1: i32) -> Self {
        Self { data: X { p1: p1 } }
    }
}

impl Z<Y> {
    fn new(p1: i32, p2: i32) -> Self {
        Self { data: Y { p1: p1, p2: p2 } }
    }
}

When creating Z<X> and Z<Y> together like this:
let zx: Z<X> = Z::new(1);
let zy: Z<Y> = Z::new(2, 3);

the compiler throws an error, presumably saying that Z::new() exists twice:
error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
  --> main.rs:33:23
   |
33 |     let zx: Z<X> = Z::new(1);
   |                       ^^^ multiple `new` found
   |

However, when creating Z<X> and Z<Y> like this:
let zx: Z<X> = Z::<X>::new(1);
let zy: Z<Y> = Z::<Y>::new(2, 3);

everything compiles just fine.
Now I am wondering:
Why does one need to manually specify the usage of <X> and <Y>, if that information should already be known given the type annotation?
And as a follow-up question:
Why does new() seem to exist twice in Z, but only once in Z<X> and  Z<Y> respectively?
Is there something about the rust type system I am not getting?

rustc version 1.77.1

(Please forgive me for possibly using some rust terminology wrong, I'm new to rust, coming from C++)

Rust does not support specialization, and what you're doing is not specialization, but two different methods for different types, that don't specialize anything.

So you're saying that if I create Z<X> and Z<Y> it's not a specialization, but a completely separate type?

Specialization is if you have a generic implementation for Z<AnyT>, and you specialize it for Z<X> and Z<Y>. You just have implementation for them.

Yes, Z<X> and Z<Y> are distinct types.  When you use Z::new without specifying the type parameter, the compiler does its best to infer what that parameter should be: if a method of that name existed for just one type parameter, it would use that—but when there are multiple matching methods it doesn't search through them to identify which have a satisfactory signature (probably a good thing as otherwise a small programming mistake could lead to very unexpected and hard to diagnose results), instead it's just an ambiguity error as you have seen.

It works if you wrap your new function and its parameter type in a factory trait. Although it would require a single constructor parameter, requiring a tuple instead of multiple arguments:
trait A {}

struct X {
    p1: i32,
}
struct Y {
    p1: i32,
    p2: i32,
}

impl A for X {}
impl A for Y {}

struct Z<T>
where
    T: A,
{
    data: T,
}

trait ZFactory {
    type Args;

    fn new(args: Self::Args) -> Self;
}

impl ZFactory for Z<X> {
    type Args = i32;

    fn new(p1: i32) -> Self {
        Self { data: X { p1 } }
    }
}

impl ZFactory for Z<Y> {
    type Args = (i32, i32);

    fn new(args: Self::Args) -> Self {
        Self {
            data: Y {
                p1: args.0,
                p2: args.1,
            },
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let zx: Z<X> = Z::new(1);
    let zy: Z<Y> = Z::new((2, 3));

    let zxa: &dyn A = &zx.data;
    let zxb: &dyn A = &zy.data;
}

